# JavaScript says 10 is lower then 9

Tags: javascript, inequality

I'm trying to learn JavaScript and when I started the MDN Tutorial, I tried to do the first exercise alone, which worked okay so far. But there is one really weird situation.

The Game generates a Random number from 1 - 100 and the User has 10 guesses to find out that number.

I simplified the game to 1 - 10 for this purpose.

When the random number is a 9 and i guess 10, the code says my input was too low. I don't understand why that is. In every other situation, it works exactly as expected.

For debugging reasons, the random number will be shown in the dialog after the first guess.

This is my code:

```
var number = 0;
var turns = 0;
var guess = 0;
var won = false;

playGame();

function playGame() {
    won = false;
    number = (Math.random() * 10).toFixed(0);
    guess = prompt("Guess a number from 1 to 10");
    turns = 0;

    while(turns < 10) {
        console.log(number + " " + guess);
        if(guess < number) {
            turns++;
            guess = prompt("Number is " + number + ".\n\nYou guessed " + turns + " Times already.\n\nYour guess was to low! Guess again:");
            won = false;
        } else if(guess > number) {
            turns++;
            guess = prompt("Number is " + number + ".\n\nYou guessed " + turns + " Times already.\n\nYour guess was to high! Guess again:");
            won = false;
        } else if(guess === number) {
            alert("You got it!");
            won = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(confirm("Wanna play again?")){
        playGame()
    } else {
        alert("kkbye!");
    }   
}
```

Thanks in advance. If you see something in my code you'd like to comment, I'd love to hear feedback and become better, even if it isn't directly related to this ;)

Comment: The `prompt()` function always returns a **string** so your comparisons are not being made with numeric values.

Comment: im gonna try to convert it to a number, thank you for the input. i believe coercion should be the right keyword for this

Comment: As @Pointy said, use parseInt(guess) to get the number out of a string.

Comment: toFixed() will also return a string. And the string "10" is smaller than the string "9". Lexical order vs numerical order.

Comment: Also you need to check for NAN condition to be on safer side :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is, that you are working with Strings, if you compare two strings with `<` it will only compare as many characters as it has to until it finds a character that is smaller (smaller being it's Integer representation) than another:

```js
console.log("10" < "9");
```

Here it will only compare `"1"` to `"9"`, meaning char code 49 to char code 57.

49 is less than 57, meaning the whole expression is `true`. You can learn more about the ASCII char codes [here](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_ascii.asp).

You should use Numbers instead:

```js
console.log(Number("10") < Number("9"));
```

You are only dealing with Strings, since both `prompt()` and `Number.toFixed()` return Strings. If you encapsulate those in `Number()` calls your game works:

```js
var number = 0;
var turns = 0;
var guess = 0;
var won = false;

playGame();

function playGame() {
    won = false;
    number = Number((Math.random() * 10).toFixed(0));
    guess = Number(prompt("Guess a number from 1 to 10"));
    turns = 0;

    while(turns < 10) {
        console.log(number + " " + guess);
        if(guess < number) {
            turns++;
            guess = prompt("Number is " + number + ".\n\nYou guessed " + turns + " Times already.\n\nYour guess was too low! Guess again:");
            won = false;
        } else if(guess > number) {
            turns++;
            guess = prompt("Number is " + number + ".\n\nYou guessed " + turns + " Times already.\n\nYour guess was too high! Guess again:");
            won = false;
        } else if(guess === number) {
            alert("You got it!");
            won = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(confirm("Wanna play again?")){
        playGame()
    } else {
        alert("kkbye!");
    }   
}
```

Comment: JavaScript (like Java, .NET, VB4/5/6, …) use UTF-16, not ASCII. UTF-16 is a character encoding for the [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) character set.

Answer (score 1):

The Javascript Prompt returns a string. In fact, input text box always returns string. So when you enter 10 it returns "10" and toFixed() will also return string.

So you need to correct two lines from your code

```
number = parseInt((Math.random() * 10).toFixed(0));
guess = prompt("Guess a number from 1 to 10");
guess = parseInt(guess);
```

Also you need to check for NAN condition to be on safer side.

Comment: thanks for the input with checking for NAN, that's a good point!